# Is there a way to have ivy display a tooltip for the function at point?

Tags: completion, ivy, tooltip

Ie, suppose I press `M-x org-agenda` and ivy says there's 131 matches, of which I recognize maybe 10. It'd be useful to say, after a .2 second delay, display a tooltip for the function at point. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. The `org-agenda` command shows the agenda commands buffer that asks you to press one of the 16 available keys. There are explanations for all. Ivy is not involved. What functions do you mean?

Comment: ivy is an interface for completion. When I type M-x "blah", ivy will try to complete that for me, and show 'n' possible completions (hope I didn't imply that I pressed return). I'm confused what you might mean by "16 keys"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like [ivy-rich](https://github.com/Yevgnen/ivy-rich).
You can configure what should be displayed in the minibuffer, including the help string of the functions. You can configure the ivy-rich-display-transformers-alist. For description of variables or functions you can configure columns:

(:columns
((counsel-M-x-transformer
(:width 40))
(ivy-rich-counsel-function-docstring
(:face font-lock-doc-face))))
counsel-describe-function
(:columns
((counsel-describe-function-transformer
(:width 40))
(ivy-rich-counsel-function-docstring
(:face font-lock-doc-face))))
counsel-describe-variable

WHich is as far as I remember already configured by default.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cool, I'll try that out. Thanks!

Comment: Oh man, I don't know how I lived without this. You, and the ivy rich maintainers are my heroes. Thanks!

Comment: Just in case you are using tramp, ivy-rich gets terribly slow if you have several remote files open. I normally just deactivate ivy-rich if using tramp excessively.